# VBA: Delete a selected line from a listbox and reset. Listbox is not assocated with any sheets in the workbook

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, listbox, userform

I have a Listbox that gets populated from several different read only sheets located in their own workbooks and also from user personal input.  Each line in the listbox is added by a command button as a smaller section of the form is being inputed by user.  If user decover they made a mistake in a individual line i need the ability to just select that line and delete it from the listbox only.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ns4FM.png)

Everything that i could find was related to the listbox being associated with a table or a sheet which is not the case for me.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/how-to/general/how-to-add-and-remove-items-from-a-list-box